How to differentiate the equation $x''=f_t+f_xf$?
I am studying differential equations of multivariable functions, and I am currently facing a problem. I would appreciate it if I could seek your help here.
$x'=f(t,x)$ and $D=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + f\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
$x''=\frac{d}{dt}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+f\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=Df$
I need to show $x'''=D^2 f+f_xDff$ but I got $x'''=D^2f+f_xDf$.
Here is the process I used to expand the equation.
$x'''=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f)\\=(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial t}f)+(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t\partial x}f+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}f^2+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d}{dt}f)\\=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+2f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial t}+f^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2})f+f_xDf\\=D^2f+f_xDf$
I would appreciate it if you could help me identify where I made a mistake and why I keep getting $f_x Df$ instead of $f_x Dff$.

Your last step is not correct, as $f$ and $\partial_x$ do not commute. Let's calculate a bit backward.
\begin{align}
D^2f &= D(\partial_tf+f\partial_xf)\\
&=\partial_t^2f+\partial_tf\partial_xf+f\partial_t\partial_xf\;+\;f\partial_x\partial_tf+f(\partial_xf)^2+f^2\partial_x^2f
\end{align}
So compared with your terms in (one $f$ removed)
$$
x'''=(\partial_t^2f+2f\partial_x\partial_tf+f^2\partial_x^2f)+\partial_xf(\partial_tf+f\partial_xf),
$$
they are identical, $x'''=D^2f$, as was intended with the introduction or use of this notation by Karl Heun in 1900, possibly this was common knowledge at the time.

I really appreciate your help. I recently started studying mathematics, so I didn't know much and was unsure which formulas or methods to look at. I'll need to study what you've explained. Your help has been really valuable to me. Thank you very much.
